# problema pass hash

Tags: php, hash, cms

Hola buenas tengo un cms y cuando me registro automaticamente el usuario logue correctamente, pero cuando desconecto e intento introducir los datos de usuario y contraseña me da error  este es el codigo que tengo para el inicio de sesión. El error que me aparece es el siguiente: You've entered wrong password. he mirado por internet pero no encuentro la solución. He modificado ya mil cosas y no encuentro la solución, estoy usando un script que es para servidores de world of warcraft y es bastante antiguo, he mirado fix de archivos pero sigue sin funcionar.

```
<?PHP
if (!defined('init_executes'))
{   
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 not found');
    exit;
}

//if the user is already logged in return him to index
if ($CURUSER->isOnline())
{
   header("Refresh: 0; url=".$config['BaseURL']."/index.php");
   exit();
}

//prepare multi errors
$ERRORS->NewInstance('login');
    
$username = (isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : false);
$password = (isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : false);
$rememberme = (isset($_POST['rememberme']) ? true : false);

if (isset($_POST['url_bl']))
{
    //check if it is valid URL
    if($CORE->ValidateURLBeforeLogin($_POST['url_bl']))
    {
        $_SESSION['url_bl'] = $_POST['url_bl'];
    }
    unset($_POST['url_bl']);
}

if (!$username)
{
    $ERRORS->Add("Please enter account name.");
}
if (!$password)
{
    $ERRORS->Add("Please enter account password.");
}

$ERRORS->Check('/index.php?page=login');

####################################################################
## The actual Login script begins here
    
    //get the column names for table accounts
    $columns = CORE_COLUMNS::get('accounts');

    //make the query to the logon database
    $res = $AUTH_DB->prepare("SELECT ".$columns['id'].", ".$columns['username'].", ".$columns['shapasshash'].", ".$columns['email'].", ".$columns['flags']." FROM `".$columns['self']."` WHERE ".$columns['username']." = :username LIMIT 1");
    
    //bind some parameters
    $res->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    
    //bind the columns for easy usage
    $res->bindColumn(1, $accid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $res->bindColumn(2, $accusername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $res->bindColumn(3, $accpasshash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $res->bindColumn(4, $accemail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $res->bindColumn(5, $accflags, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    
    //run the query
    $res->execute();
        
    //check if we have found the record
    if ($res->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        //fetch the record
        $row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        
        //make new pass hash
        $passcheck = server_Account::makehash($username, $password);

        //compare the new pass hash with the one in the record
        if ($accpasshash == $passcheck)
        { 
            $continue = false;
            
            //make some logging
            if (!$CURUSER->logInfoAtLogin($accid))
            {
                //try creating new record for this acc
                if ($CURUSER->handle_MissingRecord($accid))
                {
                    $continue = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $ERRORS->Add("The account you are trying to access is broken. Please contact the administration.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $continue = true;
            }
            
            //if the account is good to be logged in
            if ($continue)
            {
                //Login the user
                $CURUSER->setLoggedIn($accid, $passcheck);
                
                //needed for the loginb page
                $_SESSION['JustLoggedIn'] = true;
                
                
                //Remember me
                if ($rememberme)
                {
                    //Generate random salt
                    $salt = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
                    
                    //store the salt
                    $update = $DB->prepare("UPDATE `account_data` SET `salt` = :salt WHERE `id` = :acc LIMIT 1;");
                    $update->bindParam(':acc', $accid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $update->bindParam(':salt', $salt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $update->execute();
                    
                    //make the hash for the cookie
                    $newHash = sha1($accpasshash . $salt);
                    
                    //Remember the user for a month
                    $expire = strtotime('+1 month', time());
                    
                    //prepare the cookie value
                    $value = $username . '-' . $newHash;
                    
                    //set the cookie
                    $CORE->setCookie('rmm', $value, $expire);

                    //mem
                    unset($newHash, $expire, $value, $salt);
                }
                        
                //redirect
                header("Location: " . $config['BaseURL'] . "/index.php?page=loginb");
                exit;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $ERRORS->Add("You've entered wrong password.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $ERRORS->Add("The account you are trying to access does not exist.");
    }
    unset($res);

####################################################################

$ERRORS->Check('/index.php?page=login');

exit;
```

Comment: Un primer problema que veo en tu código es que estarías usando `rowCount()` para determinar si la consulta `SELECT` tiene filas. [El Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php) advierte claramente: *"`rowCount()` devuelve el número de filas afectadas por la última sentencia DELETE, INSERT, o UPDATE ejecutada por el correspondiente objeto PDOStatement...* ...

Comment: Y sigue diciendo: ... *"Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto PDOStatement asociado **fue una sentencia SELECT**, algunas bases de datos **podrían** devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia. Sin embargo, **este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos y no debería confiarse en él para aplicaciones portables**."*